# Will these gloves comply with electrical arc flash safety?

Tags: safety, arc

I am beseeching any OSHA, CalOSHA or electrical safety experts out there on this one for a little help. I know this is not strictly electrical engineering but this is the closest Stack to the topic.

Per OSHA regulations an employer is responsible for providing adequate PPE to it's workers. My electrical company is engaged in commercial industrial electrical work in the southwestern united states, mostly california, some nevada and arizona jobs. We work 99.9% with voltages of 480 and below.

NFPA 70E mandates for the PPE category selection method we are generally in category 1 and category 2 situations. in NFPA 70E table 130.7(c)(15)(a) there's a note stating if you're working on equipment at 600V or less and protected by upstream OCPDs of 200Amps or less you can reduce the category by 1, but not below category 1. Category 1 calls for leather gloves for your PPE for hand protection.

(Sorry I am getting to the question!)

H o w e v e r.
NFPA 70E is reportedly a consensus standard and is not mandatorily in force universally. Obviously OSHA laws being federal laws ARE.

My electricians (and having been an electrician myself for a few years back in the aughts, I totally understand) assert that leather gloves, even when fitted, suck for manual dexterity and in some cases present more of a hazard as you are much more likely to drop things, lose grip, have false grip, etc.

So bottom line. I want something my electricians will actually use and not remove the minute a production or safety manager walks away (before anyone says, well, your electricians suck, they're hacks, fire them, etc. look, I get it, but that's just not the way the world works. Maybe at your plant, or distribution facility, etc. it is, but for most mid size electrical companies, it's the wild west, good luck trying to get a local food storage warehouse to do an arc flash hazard analysis so we can be in compliance) Still though, safety is important to me and I want my guys protected. So if leather gloves are a requirement of a not federally enforced standard (70E) can I possibly get away with these:

Even though they are not leather, it seems they might actually exceed the cal/sq" requirements and possibly provide better protection than leather. I'm not myself an EE, though, so I could use advice.

[option 1](https://www.superiorglove.com/en/dexterity-flame-resistant-arc-flash-glove-with-neoprene-palm)

or these:

[option 2](https://www.fullsource.com/mcr-safety-9379arc/?size=4&msclkid=835d0b86020e17de3275544f709a024c&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=shop%3A%20high%20(bing)&utm_term=4584963492969217&utm_content=all%20products)

Thoughts/advice from anyone with expertise or experience is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Option 1 has an *Arc flash testing placed these gloves at level 2, with an Arc Thermal Performance Value (ATPV) of 9.2 cal/cm2*, which is greater than Category 1 requirements.  So I'd say if your people will wear them, use them.  Standards are the minimum safety requirements.  As long as you exceed them, you are fine.